# gstreamer find out decoding bit rate

Tags: gstreamer

The function `query_position(gst.FORMAT_BYTES, None)[0]` returns me the no. of bytes in the pipeline after gstreamer has decoded the video/audio. I want to know the no. of bytes of the source file that were consumed to decode till this point of time. Is there a function in gstreamer API to do this?

Comment: Finally I did this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9044262/draw-graph-of-encoded-bit-rate-of-video-vs-play-location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read the [seeking](http://pygstdocs.berlios.de/pygst-tutorial/seeking.html) chapter from pygst docs. You can replace `pos_int = self.player.query_position(gst.FORMAT_TIME, None)[0]` with your version to get the bytes in real time. They are using `thread` object.

You can also add the [timeout method](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/manual/html/chapter-queryevents.html#section-querying). In [Python](http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2reference/gobject-functions.html#function-gobject--timeout-add) its `gobject.timeout_add(interval, callback, ...)`

Answer (score 0):

I have received the download data size in souphttpsrc source using onGotChunk event. This onGotChunk is MPEGDASH specific patch for souphttpsrc element.

In general 
`gboolean gst_element_query_duration (GstElement *element,                      GstFormat format, gint64 *duration);` this API can be used. Pass source element as a 1st argument to this function and check.